# Generated QR code not displaying on mobile

Tags: php, html, qr-code

I am using php qr code to generate a QR code. The code displays in browser, and stays when I shrink down the width to mobile, but it does not display at all on my mobile browser, both Chrome and and Firefox. Any ideas?

```
require_once(APPLICATION_PATH.'/library/phpqrcode-master/qrlib.php');
ob_start();
\QRcode::png($id, null, 'M', 8, 2);
$endingOutput = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

return '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($endingOutput).'" /><br/>' . $bitcoinID;
```

Comment: Where's the code you're using? There's no information to actually go on here, but making random guesses.

Comment: @Sherif updated my question

Comment: [Not all browsers support data URIs](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri), and many have limitations. Check `strlen(base64_encode($endingOutput))` to see the size of the image. If it's large than 32K you may see issues in some mobile browsers. Also, this could just be an CSS/HTML or other client side specific issue. There's really no way to tell without access to a reproducible example. See [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of what was causing the issue exactly, but a workaround that fixed my problem was creating a div and creating the div's background url to be the base64 code. I was loading it in with ajax

```
var url = 'url(data:image/png;base64,' + data.base64 + ') no-repeat';
$("#somediv").css("background", url);
```

I also had to set the divs width and height for it to display.